# Is this geometric Brownian Motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The SDE for GBM is usually specified as:

$$dX(t) = X(t)[\mu dt + \sigma dW(t)]$$

If we model diffusion as stochastic, **is the following still GBM?**

$$dX(t) = X(t)[\mu dt + \sigma_t dW(t)]$$

---

$\sigma_t$ is stochastic and is driven to an independent Brownian motion.

Comment: $\sigma_t$ deterministic ?

Comment: $\sigma(t)$ is stochastic and has a separate Wiener process inside of it.

Comment: Then you won't get geometric brownian motion.  An example is $\sigma_t = \frac 1 {\sqrt{X_t}}$ giving you a well known square root diffusion.  (If $\sigma_t$ is deterministic you get a process whose log in has gaussian independent increments which are not stationary)